# FileSystemStorage issue

Tags: codenameone

this issue start appeared in some android devices before two weeks

```
Display.getInstance().openGallery(new ActionListener<ActionEvent>() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
if(evt!=null&&evt.getSource()!=null){
String imageFilePath = (String) evt.getSource();

Image.createImage(FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(imageFilePath));

}

}, Display.GALLERY_IMAGE);
```

> FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openInputStream(imageFilePath)

> java.lang.stackoverflowerror: stack size …

the app stuck and after while the error appeared

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add build hint

> codename1.arg.android.xapplication_attr=android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"